# What is the range of the function $f(x)=\frac{4x(x^2+1)}{x^2+(x^2+1)^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, fractions, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

What is the range of the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{4x(x^2+1)}{x^2+(x^2+1)^2}
$$
with $x\ge0$?

I can't find a right method to solve this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The limit for $x\rightarrow \infty$ is $0$ because numerator has degree $3$ and denominator degree $4$, so you only have to determine the extrema. Also consider $f(0)=0$

Comment: @Peter I think the domain is $[0,\infty).$

Comment: @zhw. that's mentioned in the question itself....

Comment: @Carrick Yes, I noticed that a little later. I edited my comment.

Comment: @Peter the value of f(x) at $x\to \infty$ is unfortunately of no use.

Comment: Hint: the answer to aim for https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aq4rweyifu

Comment: @Carrick You need this limit for the range. The global maximum of the function is $1.6$, so the range is $[0,1.6]$

Comment: The answer is $[0,\frac{8}{5}]$

Comment: i already knew the answer but i am still unable to find a way out to solve this question.

Comment: @Carrick Do you know derivates and how to determine (local) extrema ?

Comment: @Peter yh i do...

Comment: @Carrick That is exactly what you need. The limit and $f(0)$ are necessary to detect that the local maximum is in fact the global maximum. This immediately gives the range.

Comment: As peter stated almost instantly after I posted my answer, this is exactly what you need to do. Do not get scared of the fraction for its derivative, such simple cases are simple to handle since you can just apply the fraction differentiation rule which I'm sure you've been taught too.

Comment: @Rebellos Often this rule is called "quotient rule" and without it, I would not have an idea how to solve the exercise with reasonable effort.

Comment: @Peter Correct ! I'm Greek so I definitely need to brush my terminology skills ! The quotient rule isn't hard to be proved though and in such cases I'm pretty sure the OP is taking an elementary calculus class regarding exactly such stuff, as you also mentioned ! The comments and the contributions were on point and correct !

Comment: oh okay...thanks for helping

Comment: and i know the quotient rule very well lol...i knew about this method but i was just curious if there was a different way to solve this question....but i guess the differentiation method is good in itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's obvious that $f(x)\geq0.$

Let $x>0$ and $x+\frac{1}{x}=2t$.

Thus, by AM-GM $$2t=x+\frac{1}{x}\geq2\sqrt{x\cdot\frac{1}{x}}=2,$$ which says $t\geq1$.

The equality occurs for $x=1$.

Thus, by AM-GM again $$f(x)=\frac{4}{\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{x^2+1}{x}}=\frac{4}{\frac{1}{2t}+2t}=\frac{4}{\frac{1}{2t}+\frac{t}{2}+1.5t}\leq\frac{4}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2t}\cdot\frac{t}{2}}+1.5}=\frac{8}{5}.$$
Since $f$ is a continuous function, we got the answer: $$\left[0,\frac{8}{5}\right]$$

Comment: hey thanks for the answer..i just had a doubt..where did you get the intuition to split 2t into 0.5t and 1.5t?? If it was me i wouldn't have done that and would've got the wrong answer

Comment: @Carrick Because we know that the equality occurs for $x=1$ or for $t=1$ and in AM-GM the equality occurs for $\frac{1}{2t}=\frac{t}{2},$ which gives $t=1$ again.

Answer (score 5):

The derivative of $f(x)$ is :

$$f'(x) = - \frac{4(x^6-1)}{(x^4 + 3x^2 +1)^2}$$

I'll leave the calculation of it to you, since it's a simple fraction derivative application, just make sure to be careful to not make any numerical mistakes, as its calculation is very easy, by applying the fraction differentiation rule :

$$\bigg( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\bigg)' = \frac{f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{g^2(x)}$$

Obviously, the denominator of the fraction is always positive, since : $(x^4 + 3x^2 + 1)^2 > 0$ .

This means that the sign of the derivative depends on the sign of the numerator, specifically :

$$4(x^6-1) > 0 \Rightarrow x^6 - 1 > 0 \Rightarrow x>1 \space \text{or} \space x < -1$$

But on the exercise it's mentioned that we're exploring over $x \geq 0$, so this means that we will only take into account the solution of the inequality : $x>1$.

This means that at $x=1$ your function changes sign, which by elementary calculus rules this means that this is a global maximum for your function, which will specifically be :

$$f(1) = \frac{8}{5}$$

So, in the domain $x \in \mathbb [0,+ \infty)$, we only need to check its behavior at infinite, to determine whether we'll need another value :

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x(x^2+1)}{x^2+(x^2+1)^2}=0$$

which means that the function asymptotically tends to $0$ as $x$ becomes very large.

Also note that $f(0) = 0$.

These are enough to conclude that the range of the values of the function for $x\geq 0$, are :

$$f([0, + \infty))= [0, 8/5]$$

Comment: how did you calculate the derivative of the function so easily??

Comment: is there any alternative method?? because using this technique of calculating the derivative is surely to consume a lot of my precious time during exams

Comment: @Carrick The derivative of the function is easy to calculate, I just left the calculations out so that you could practice, as I saw from the comments that you were a bit scared to handle it. I added the fraction differentiation rule that should help you get there easily ! Regarding alternative methods, in mathematics most often than not, one could provide tons of solutions for such elementary questions. Since you're taking an elementary calculus class though as I judge from the question and your sayings, this is **exactly** what you're expected to do to handle the exercise.

Comment: @Carrick Changing the accepted answer to an answer that also differentiates but with another way and does the exact same thing is something I cannot explain.

Comment: no offense buddy. but that method is a bit shorter. that's all...but if you want I can still set your answer as the official answer to this question

Comment: @Carrick No mate, it's your choice and you should leave it to the other answer, since it's what you found to be the answer of your problem. I don't mind for the points, I just didn't get the difference between the answers, other than making the differentiation more complicated with no reason. But since the other answer is what you thought was the most alternatively fitted to you, you should definitely leave the answered tag to the other answer, so please refrain to your initial selection ! :) Just wondered where the difference was!

Answer (score 1):

For $u\in]-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2[$ let's substitute $x=\tan(u)$

$f(x)=\dfrac{4x(1+x^2)}{x^2+(1+x^2)^2}=\dfrac{\frac{4\sin(u)}{\cos(u)^3}}{\frac{\sin(u)^2\cos(u)^2+1}{\cos(u)^4}}=\dfrac{4\sin(u)\cos(u)}{1+\sin(u)^2\cos(u)^2}=\dfrac{2\sin(2u)}{1+\frac 14\sin(2u)^2}=\dfrac{8s}{4+s^2}$

With $s=\sin(2u)\in]-1,1[$.

Let's set $g(x)=\dfrac{8x}{4+x^2}$

$g'(x)=\dfrac{-8(x-2)(x+2)}{(4+x^2)^2}>0$ on the given interval so $g\nearrow$.

The extrema are thus given for the bounds of the interval : $g(1)=\dfrac 85$ and $g(-1)=-\dfrac 85$.

Since $g$ is continuous all values in $]-\frac 85,\frac 85[$ are reached.

The substitution between $x$ and $u$ being bijective, we conclude the same for the range of $f$.

Comment: I couldn't understand how did you find value of x where $f(x)$ attains a maxima

Comment: I didn't calculated this value of $x$. I found $g$ range and said $f$ range was the same. $g$ range is easy to find because it is strictly increasing on an interval so the extremum values are reached at the bounds.

Comment: oh okay...got ya...thank you